# Navigate through a lookup relationship inside a PageblockTable

Tags: visualforce, lookup, pageblocktable

I have two Objects: Prodotti_e_Servizi__c and Prodotto_contratto__c. In Prodotti_e_Servizi__c I have a field Prezzo_giornaliero__c  instead  in Prodotto_contratto__c I have a lookup relationship called Scelta__c to Prodotti_e_Servizi__c. The relationship name is Opportunit_contratti__r.

My question is: How can I show the field  Prezzo_giornaliero__c of the related Prodotti_e_Servizi__c, inside a pageblocktable of List.

Now I'm trying something like : {!Prodotti_e_Servizi__c.Opportunit_contratti__r.Prezzo_giornaliero__c.sc.Scelta__c} but it's not working.

the pageblocktable is:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!shoppingCart}" var="sc" id="tabella">
                    <apex:column headerValue="ID ">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!sc.Id}" target="_blank">{!sc.Id}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Prodotto " value="{!sc.Scelta__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Gioni di noleggio "> 
                    <apex:outputField value="{!sc.Giorni_durata_noleggio__c}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>
                    </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quantità ">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!sc.Quantit_prodotto__c}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>
                    </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Sconto% " >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!sc.Sconto__c}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>
                    </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Azioni">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteRow}" immediate="true" reRender="tabella" value="CANC">
                    <apex:param name="rowid" value="{!sc.Id}" assignTo="{!SelectedRowId}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

where shoppingCart is the List of Prodotto_contratto__c.

Answer (score 0):

Now the reference is working:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Prz noleggio(gg) " value="{!sc.Scelta__r.Prezzo_giornaliero__c }"/>
```

I find the correct relatioship name Scelta__r, but in the table Prezzo_giornaliero__c doesn't appear, why? I don't understand

Comment: Please check the field level security for field "Prezzo_giornaliero__c".